# Jquery multiple class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Why does the following code only work once?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".fb.unselect").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("unselect").addClass("select");
  });
  $(".fb.select").click(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("select").addClass("unselect");
    alert("hellp");
  });
});

<li id="177200175" class="fb select">Donald Steele</li>
```

Comment: What do you mean it works once?How many should work?

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this type of thing is to use toggleClass.

Your question is not that clear, but reading between the lines I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fb").toggleClass('selected');
});
```

This will have the effect of adding the class 'selected' when it is NOT present, and removing it when it was. You can use css to control what the presence of that class does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the functions you're defining on document load are only binded at that particular moment. Thus, even if you change the element's classes, it will not be magically autobinded to the other function.

As a result of that the latter function is always called, which tries to remove class `select` and add class `unselect`, which leads to the problem that the class only changes once to `unselect` and stays that way ever since, as you said.

To fix your example using two different classes as in your question, do it like this for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fb").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('select')) {
            $(this).removeClass('select').addClass('unselect');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('unselect').addClass('select');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Adz6/1/).